# How to call applyFilter function on GridView

Tags: javascript, yii2

Instead of using Pjax, which is giving me some problems, i would like to know how to apply the filter in a Yii2 GridView using javascript.

In the yii.gridView.js (loaded on yii2 every time you use the GridView widget) there are this lines inside var methods:

```
 applyFilter: function () {
        var $grid = $(this);
        var settings = gridData[$grid.attr('id')].settings;
        var data = {};
        $.each($(settings.filterSelector).serializeArray(), function () {
            if (!(this.name in data)) {
                data[this.name] = [];
            }
            data[this.name].push(this.value);
```

});
...

How do i call this function using javascript inside my page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try

```
grid.yiiGridView("applyFilter");
```

where `grid` is a GridView (i.e. element of `.grid-view` class).

Comment: It works, using jquery
$('#grid-view-id').yiiGridView("applyFilter");

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.grid-view').yiiGridView("applyFilter");
```